# PHP - How to use !ctype in float?

Tags: php

I normally always use !ctype_digit in php so I can enter numberic. however I have a task that require to enter in float (ex: 123.12) I have no idea so I'm request for help 
here is my code below:

```
        // Payment Amount Validation
if (isset($_POST['paymentam'])) {

    // get value from post after trimming leading and trailing soaces
    $paymentam = trim($_POST['paymentam']);
    // test for missing input
    if (strlen($paymentam) == 0) {
        $errors['paymentam'] = "Missing Input";
    } else {
        // remove spaces from first name value
        $temp = str_replace(' ', '', $paymentam);
        // test for alpha only
        if (!ctype_digit($temp)) {
            $errors['paymentam'] = "Enter numberics only";
        }
    }
} // end Payment Amount Validation
```

Comment: !ctype_float but doesn't seem to work

Comment: what about `if ((string) floatval($temp) != $temp) {/* logic */}` ?

Comment: Is regex an option `if(preg_match('/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/', $temp)` requires 1 or more digits, then optionally a decimal followed by one or more digits. And of course match the whole thing start to end.  [Test It](https://regex101.com/r/mXpD50/1)  Coincidently if you need to check if it's only a float, just remove the `(?:...)?` optional non-capture group, but leave the `\.\d+`

Comment: if you want a non-regx way to check for decimals then if(strlen($temp)==strlen((int)$temp)) if it's a float (or string) the length will change. There are like 3 type casts in there, but it works..  [test it](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/659a2b31abf033d0d7392e57bf3fbc3927b82480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctype_digit` check for `all digits` in given value not for `float` value. [Check in this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php#refsect1-function.ctype-digit-examples)

You can use `is_numeric` to check entered value is `integer` or `float`

```
<?php
 $temp = "123.12";
  if (!is_numeric($temp)) {
    echo "Enter numeric only";
  }else{
  echo "validated";
  }
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1055384)

Comment: is_numeric can be problematic if you plan on saving the value inside a database: `is_numeric('12e3') === true`